# jquery replace regex using dynamic token

Tags: jquery, regex, string, replace

I am trying to replace a variety of strings (tokens) in a textarea using jquery replace(). I can make it work except it only replaces the first occurrence in the textarea and need it to do all.

I'm able to do the replacements like this;

```
var token = '{IP}';

sdText = sdText.replace(token, $('.' + data.name).val());
```

I'm needing to do this instead to catch all occurrences;

```
var token = '{IP}';

sdText = sdText.replace(/token/g, $('.' + data.name).val());
```

because there may be multiple occurrences of the token in the textarea I need replaced. The value of token changes per each iteration of an .each() loop, I need that value injected into the regex statement for each iteration.

Does anyone know how I would accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic `regex` use [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) constructor.

```
var regex = new RegExp(token, 'g');

sdText = sdText.replace(regex, $('.' + data.name).val());
```